# Find the result of the $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}}{\ln n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, logarithms, infinity, harmonic-functions

Does there exist an alternative way to demonstrate and evaluate the result of the following limit without using an asymptotic expansion?
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k}}{\ln n}$$
Using a spreadsheet presumably the result of the limit is $1$, and watching other posts like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4068536/does-lim-k-to-infty-sum-n-1k-frac1n-ln-k-exists?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3960323/relationship-between-partial-harmonic-sum-and-logarithm?rq=1) related about Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma$, the result is obtained immediately.
$${\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k}}{\ln n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\dfrac{\ln n+\gamma+O\begin{pmatrix}\dfrac{1}{n}\end{pmatrix}}{\ln n}}=1$$
Is that correct? However, I would like to know if there is other way to calculate that result using calculus in a context of firsts courses of engineering careers. Maybe with convergence criteria for series?

Comment: Compare the sum to $\int_a^b \frac{dx}{x}$, with suitable values for $a$ and $b$ (to get an upper and a lower bound).

Comment: See also these questions, for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564087/prove-lnn-diverges-as-quickly-as-the-harmonic-series/1564106, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733438/asymptotic-equivalence-between-harmonic-numbers-and-logarithm

Comment: Have a look at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9687/42969 about (not!) using `\displaystyle` and `\dfrac` in titles.